# Момент получения информации от пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net

Приступил к изучению asp.net и возник следующий вопрос.

Если в событии Page_Init в TextBox прописать какое-либо значение, например, 0, то при get запросе страницы этот TextBox будет содержать это значение, что и понятно. При изменении пользователем страницы в TextBox этого значения (т.е. с нуля, например, к 10) и отправки Post запроса приложение будет работать с новым пользовательским значением, т.е. с 10.

Обратная картина происходит, если вместо события Page_Init воспользоваться событием Page_Load. Без проверки (!isPostBack) при PostBack запросе пользовательское значение 10 скидывается на 0.

Т.е. получается, что пользовательские данные считываются после события Page_Init (пользовательская 10 перезаписалась вместо 0), но до события Page_Load (0 перезаписал пользовательскую 10).

В какой конкретно момент времени они считываются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значения считываются дважды

1. Между OnInitComplete и OnPreLoad
2. Между OnLoad и ChangedEvents (для тех контролов, которые были созданы динамически в OnLoad)

Обработкой занимается [метод ProcessPostData](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Page.cs,3041), в комментариях расписаны моменты вызова:

```
/*
 * This method will process the data posted back in the request header.
 * The collection of posted data keys consists of three types :
 * 1.  Fully qualified ids of controls.  The associated value is the data
 *     posted back by the browser for an intrinsic html element.
 * 2.  Fully qualified ids of controls that have explicitly registered that
 *     they want to be notified on postback.  This is required for intrinsic
 *     html elements that for some states do not postback data ( e.g. a select
 *     when there is no selection, a checkbox or radiobutton that is not checked )
 *     The associated value for these keys is not relevant.
 * 3.  Framework generated hidden fields for event processing, whose values are
 *     set by client-side script prior to postback.
 *
 * This method handles the process of notifying the relevant controls that a postback
 * has occurred, via the IPostBackDataHandler interface.
 *
 * It can potentially be called twice: before and after LoadControl.  This is to
 * handle the case where users programmatically add controls in Page_Load (ASURT 29045).
 */
```